# Semantic Sermentation, about the mask?

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

If I get the mask on the feature map, for example, a 7 x 7 feature map, how can  these 7 x 7 masks finally become the mask on the raw image?
Using interpolation or upsampling? As far as I'm concerned, if you do mask on a 7 x 7 feature map where you only have 49 pixels, will it be too rough to mask the object in the raw image, for you cannot be too specific on only 49 pixels...

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You simply use a bigger mask, where are you getting the 7x7 feature map from?

Comment: In Mask R-CNN, the author uses the resnet/fcn last layer feature which is 7 x 7 or 14 x 14, and he just does mask operation on them.

Comment: Mask R-CNN outputs a 28x28 mask, not a 7x7 one.